# How does the RavenDB windows service serve web pages?

Tags: web, windows-services, ravendb

I run RavenDB as a windows service. How is it serving web pages? I don't see any HTML or ASPX files in the RavenDB folder structure.

Furthermore, when I start the service and run this command:

> netstat -an | find "8080"

I get this result:

> TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING
>   TCP [::]:8080    [::]:0 LISTENING

If the windows service is listening on **TCP** 8080, then why can I access the Raven Studio from a browser via **HTTP**?

```
http://server:8080/raven/studio.html
```

I know I'm missing something fundamental, but I'm not sure how this comes together, and I'd like to know because I think it would help me with how to figure out how to secure the DB and Raven Studio. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is a layer on top of TCP.  **All** web servers will show as TCP using a tool like netstat.

You don't need to have html or aspx files to speak http.  Internally, raven uses [System.Net.HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/34xswsd2.aspx) if you are running as a service or in console mode.  (It can also run inside of IIS, or be embedded directly in your application).

Regarding security, RavenDB has many options:

- Windows Authentication
- [Anonymous Access](http://ravendb.net/docs/http-api/http-api-security)
- [OAuth](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/authentication)
- [Mixed Mode](https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/d87a67d0b1a516c)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I'm having an issue with Windows Authentication. If you feel like helping: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13588064/279516