# restrict Access to Panel administration for ravendb

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I've tried to add a windows authentication to the panel removing setting the anonymous access to none, but I'm still able to browse the site with the IP:RavendbPort in the browser, how can I set up the panel to ask for windows auth.

I have read that practically the panel is like another site in IIS but where can I configure that?

I'm using IIS 8 and this is the following xml for the Raven.Server.exe.config I'm runnign ravendb as a service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Raven/Port" value="2211"/>
    <add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\Database\System"/>
    <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="None"/>  <!-- Settings are Get, All, None -->
        <add key="Raven/Authorization/Windows/RequiredUsers" value=myservername/username"/>
  </appSettings>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="Analyzers;Plugins"/>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I have read the following question to [restrict access to ravendb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034780/how-to-restrict-access-to-admin-panel-in-ravendb) but with no luck!

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This value:

```
        <add key="Raven/Authorization/Windows/RequiredUsers" value=myservername/username"/>
```

Is only value in 1.0

In 2.0, you are already experiencing this behavior. What probably tricks you is that the browser cache credentials sometimes, and automatically authenticate for you.

Comment: Hi Ayende, I removed the line from the file, restarted the service, I can still browse the site however every time I wanted to perform any operation I got the window credentials prompted, but how can I restrict the whole access to the admin? do you recommend this approach? http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2010/12/13/setting-up-ravendb-as-an-iis-application-by-pictures/